# how to save an id return by a library project in a database c#

Tags: c#, database, database-connection, class-library, mifare

I have a project class library that manipulate Mifare Card, I can read the UID of this card and the next step I want to create a data base to store this UID.

I want to khow how can I create this database ? and how can I import it on my project class library. 
Should I use Entity Framework ?

How can I save UID on the database ?

I thank you in advance

Comment: Answers of all the questions are available on Google. You need to research, read, learn and apply the knowledge in code. If you face any problem in the code, you can ask question here and surely you will get solution to  your problem.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I already checked on google before I Ask my question here, 
I will search again 
Thank you !